# Span elements with contenteditable don't lose focus naturally, unlike div elements

Tags: html, css, contenteditable

> JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sharat87/qWCQT/

As you can (or can't) see in the jsfiddle above, when you click below a `div` element with `contenteditable`, it loses focus, and rightfully so. But when you do the same thing with a `span` element with `contenteditable`, it *doesn't* lose focus. Also, `div` element with the style `display: inline-block` behaves exactly like the `span` element in this scenario.

In my app's layout, I need the `contenteditable` element to display as an `inline-block`. But it should lose focus when clicked on the empty space given below, which is explicitly provided for losing focus and a context specific purpose. I don't want the `contenteditable` element to retain focus.

Any way around this, short of handling the click and `blur`-ing the `contenteditable` element through javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just added `style/display property` with JavaScript depending on `Browser` and it worked

```
window.onload=function(){
    var ua=navigator.userAgent;
    var spans=document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for(i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
    {
        if(spans[i].className=='content')
        {
            if(ua.indexOf('MSIE')!=-1) spans[i].style.display='inline-block'; 
            else spans[i].style.display='inline-table'; 
        }
    }
};
```

Tested in Chrome, FF, IE8 and Opera. An [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/qWCQT/2/).

Comment: Yep, that seems to solve the problem. I'll read up on `inline-table`. Thank you.